# Windows 10 says "driver missing" for Canon EOS 550D

Tags: canon, canon-550d, windows, usb

I have recently upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10. The camera (Canon EOS 550D) worked fine beforehand and I can still access it nicely on the same computer when booting into Linux. Thus, the hardware is fine. But when I try to access it from Windows 10, it says that the driver is missing. [However, according to Canon, no driver should be required:](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/cameras/digital_slr/eos_550d.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=WINDOWS%2010%20(64-bit))

> This product is compatible with the operating system selected and when connected to a computer via a USB cable the camera should be automatically detected as a media device. It is not required to install a driver.

The camera does not appear in Explorer. The Windows 10 installation is only 1 day old. I am using the original USB cable for the connection. What am I missing?

Comment: Related, when going from Windows 7 to Windows 8: [EOS Utility does not detect my 550D](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27078/eos-utility-does-not-detect-my-550d)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason was that I am using Windows 10 N, which comes without the MTP driver. One has to install the Microsoft Media Feature Pack, in order to get this driver. Windows Update does not find it automatically. Moreover, for me it did not work out to install [this version of the driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48231) which is linked almost everywhere. Instead, I had to install the 1803 version of [this download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack). The 1809 version did not work either.